# Create an object of arrays with combining two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, array-map

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enctgg-dvagm3
Problem statement : Am trying to patch the hours from arr2 to arr1 and then build the whole expected o/p as given below.

I was trying with map. But not sure how to traverse through nested array.
Note : Array1 has nested array and need to map those into arrar2
**code :**

```
var result = this.responseValue.map((person, index) => ({ ppmInfoId: { locationCode: person.locationCode, yearMonth: person.locationType, changeOrderId: 20 },  hours: index}));
```

**Expected output :**

```
"ppmInfo": [
  {
    "ppmInfoId": {
      "changeOrderId": 0,
      "locationCode": 1,
      "yearMonth": "May/2021"
    },
    "hours": "10"
  },
  {
    "ppmInfoId": {
      "changeOrderId": 0,
      "locationCode": 1,
      "yearMonth": "June/2021"
    },
    "hours": "20"
  },      {
    "ppmInfoId": {
      "changeOrderId": 0,
      "locationCode": 2,
      "yearMonth": "May/2021"
    },
    "hours": "10"
  },
  {
    "ppmInfoId": {
      "changeOrderId": 0,
      "locationCode": 3,
      "yearMonth": "May/2021"
    },
    "hours": "10"
  }
]
```

**Input Array 1 :**

```
 this.responseValue = [
          {
            locationCode: '1',
            locationType: 'Onsite',
            ppmDetailsToList: [
              {
                hours: 0,
                changeOrderId: null,
                yearMonth: 'May/2021',                
              },
              {
                hours: 0,
                changeOrderId: null,
                yearMonth: 'June/2021',                
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            locationCode: '2',
            locationType: 'Offshore',
            ppmDetailsToList: [
              {
                hours: 0,
                changeOrderId: null,
                yearMonth: 'May/2021',                
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            locationCode: '3',
            locationType: 'offsite',
            ppmDetailsToList: [
              {
                hours:0,
                changeOrderId: null,
                yearMonth: 'May/2021',
                locationCode: 0
              },
            ]
          }
        ];
```

**Input array 2 :**

```
[{ "Onsite": [ 10, 20 ], "Offshore": [ 10 ], "offsite": [ 10 ] }]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array1 = [{
    locationCode: '1',
    locationType: 'Onsite',
    ppmDetailsToList: [{
      hours: 0,
      changeOrderId: null,
      yearMonth: 'May/2021',
    }, ]
  },
  {
    locationCode: '2',
    locationType: 'Offshore',
    ppmDetailsToList: [{
      hours: 0,
      changeOrderId: null,
      yearMonth: 'May/2021',
    }, ]
  },
  {
    locationCode: '3',
    locationType: 'offsite',
    ppmDetailsToList: [{
      hours: 0,
      changeOrderId: null,
      yearMonth: 'May/2021',
      locationCode: 0
    }, ]
  }
];
const array2 = [{
  "Onsite": [10],
  "Offshore": [10],
  "offsite": [10]
}]

const result = {
  ppmInfo: array1.map(({ 
    locationCode, 
    locationType, 
    ppmDetailsToList: [{ hours, changeOrderId, yearMonth }]
  }) =>({
    hours: array2[0][locationType][0],
    ppmInfoId: {
      changeOrderId: changeOrderId || 0,
      locationCode,
      yearMonth
    }
  }))
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, But there are possibilities in array1 has multiple objects inside ppmDetailsToList. need to address that as well to create a separate object out of it. am updating the array1

Answer (score 0):

Used foreach itself to get the desired output. Closing this